# How To Remove random string name in my List and Print the the name Removed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried many hours here my code snippet
when i run the code it only remove the index I want to remove the name and print the name removed

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> names = new List<string>();

    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            Debug.Log(name);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            int index = Random.Range(0, names.Count);
            names.Remove(names[index]);
            Debug.Log("Removed: " + names[index]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @AnuViswan okay my bad

Comment: Note that the upper parameter of `Random.Range` is **exclusive**! That means e.g. that `Random.Range(0, 8)` will only return the values `0` to `7` and **never** `8` ... You rather want to use `Random.Range(0, names.Count)`

Comment: Btw alternatively to removing them you could also "shuffle" your list and then simply return them sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a random index with you, then first save the name to a variable, then use the same index to remove the item from the list

```
//Example names = { "suleiman", "Jon Skeet", "Prasad T"} & index = 2;
var nameTobeRemove = names[index];  //"Prasad T"
names.RemoveAt(index);  // "Prasad T" removed

Console.WriteLine($"Removed name : {nameTobeRemove}");  //"Removed name :Prasad T"
Console.WriteLine($"New List : {string.Join(", ", names)}"); // New List : suleiman, Jon Skeet
```

---

The problem in your code is, you are not saving `name` before removal, my above solution does that. It saves `name` which is going to remove to a variable.

Comment: i will try and let you know Thanks

Comment: @suleiman Sure, let me know if you need more assistance, I hope this will work.

Comment: wooow Thanks  @Prasad Telkikar It works

Comment: @suleiman, great. If it works then do not forget to accept it. Your acceptance will help others to identify the correct solution for this kind of problems